# Why cannot I select the next DIV sibling using pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, closest, nextsibling

I have two `div` elements with one button in the first div as follows.

```
<div class='my-class'>
    <div class='other-div'>
       <button onClick="nextDiv(this);">Click</button>
    </div> 
</div> 
<div class='my-class'>
</div>
```

Below is my JavaScript code.

```
function nextDiv(element) {
      element.closest('.my-class').style.display = 'none';
      element.closest('.my-class').nextSibling.style.display = 'block';
}
```

When I click on the button, why can I hide the first element but cannot show the next div element with the class `my-class`. Instead, I get the following error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined
```

It seems like I cannot select the next div element of the class `my-class` using the nextSibling property. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I would bet that `nextSibling` returns a text node (you could use `nextElementSibling` to ensure the next element is returned instead). Text nodes do not have `style` properties, so `nextSibling.style.display` fails.

Comment: because of the space between divs

Comment: `.closest()` is a jQuery function. It returns a jQuery object, not a DOM element.

Comment: I don't understand how you're getting that far. `element` is a DOM element, not a jQuery object, so `element.closest()` should complain of trying to call a non-function. If you're trying to do this in plain JS, why do you have jQuery mixed in?

Comment: @Barmar https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Comment: @Stijn Thanks -- I guess the JS designers are trying to put jQuery out of business :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: yes it solved the problem using nextElementSibling. You have saved my day! Thanks! and Thank you all for any comment!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) returns a text node in this case:

```
<TextNode textContent=" \n">
```

Use [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling) instead.

From [MDN: Node.nextSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling)

> Gecko-based browsers insert text nodes into a document to represent whitespace in the source markup. Therefore a node obtained, for example, using Node.firstChild or Node.previousSibling may refer to a whitespace text node rather than the actual element the author intended to get.